# review fb button with rating

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to put a button on my website to allow our customers to place reviews on our Facebook page. I need this button to open up a dialog similar to the FB.ui feed dialog but with the possibility to rate the comment with that 5 stars style used on Facebook reviews? Can I do that with php o javascript?

My code for feed:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            x$.ready(function () {
                x$('#share_button').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    FB.ui(
                        {
                            method: 'feed',
                            name: '<?php echo $linkname;?>',
                            link: '<?php echo $link;?>',
                            <?php if (isset($campaign->facebook_image) && $campaign->facebook_image != '' && $campaign->facebook_image != null) { ?>
                            picture: '<?php echo 'bo.opinat.com' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'facebookimages' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $campaign->id . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$campaign->facebook_image; ?>',
                            <? } ?>
                            caption: '<?php echo $linkcaption;?>',
                            description: '<?php echo $linkdescription;?>'
                        },
                        function (response) {
                            if (response && !response.error_message) {
                                FB.api('/' + response.post_id, function (response) {
                                    x$().xhr('<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('survey/saveSocialMediaPost', array('answer_id' => $answer->id, 'social_network' => 1, 'state' => 'P', 'user_id' => $campaignCenter->social_media_user)); ?>', {
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        async: true,
                                        data: 'message=' + response.message + '&post_id=' + response.id,
                                    });
                                    console.log(response.message);
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                x$().xhr('<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('survey/saveSocialMediaPost', array('answer_id' => $answer->id, 'social_network' => 1, 'state' => 'E', 'user_id' => $campaignCenter->social_media_user)); ?>', {
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    async: true,
                                    data: 'message=' + response.error_message + '&post_id=' + response.error_code,
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    );
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: the usual question: what have you tried so far? please include your research and your code.

Comment: Hi luschn, what I'm tried to do is feed automatically my customer's opinions on my Facebook page. I'm doing with feed but I need to add review stars.

Comment: now you´ve lost me. do you want to post reviews to facebook? or do you want to create your own rating system with stars?

Comment: Only to post reviews.

Comment: in that case, the answer is very easy

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the docs, you can´t post reviews/ratings with the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings#Creating

> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.